Selecting and displaying image in html
here is my little form  code in html, which allows user to  select image
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Select image </title>
</head>
<body>
<form >

    <label for="img"> Select image </label>
    <input type ="file" id="img" name ="img" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submti">
    
</form>




</body>
</html>

result is :

when i am selecting some image, it displays name of it, for instance  result looks like this :

but my question is : how to display the same image? of course  if i  know exactly that this image  was selected, i will display it by default, but  i want to make it user dependent, how can i do it? thanks in advance

No worries. Does this answer your question? Preview an image before it is uploaded

just i  would like to know, how to add all this to my code?

ok i have done it, now comes python question  in a few minute

You can use JavaScript to display an image by changing the  tag source on the selection with a function call. Here is an example:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Select image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="img">Select image</label>
        <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*" onchange="displayImage(this)">
        <br>
        <img id="selectedImg" src="#" alt="Selected Image" style="display:none; max-width: 300px;">
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
        function displayImage(input) {
            var file = input.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var imgElement = document.getElementById('selectedImg');
                imgElement.src = e.target.result;
                imgElement.style.display = 'block';
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

